# Tiered pricing in Stripe using redirectToCheckout

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a subscription set up using redirectToCheckout in Stripe (the reason for this is that I want to be able to pass the user's email over to checkout whereas the other methods e.g. creating a payment link don't seem to allow for this). However I now want to set up a tiered pricing subscription where people are charged x amount for 1 month and then this goes up. I'm not sure how to implement this and all the information online (including coupons) doesn't apply to using redirectToCheckout, I've spoken to support and they say it's not possible I just feel like it must be??!

Thanks in advance.

```
<script>
    (function() {
      var stripe = Stripe('pk_live_ypJHVNfZxImi4GIGIqrfmiqg00FihqI33x');

      var checkoutButton = document.getElementById('checkout-button-price_1Kib7bGscxiBsp7B6t0AXfBk');
      checkoutButton.addEventListener('click', function () {
        /*
         * When the customer clicks on the button, redirect
         * them to Checkout.
         */
        stripe.redirectToCheckout({
          lineItems: [{price: 'price_1Kib7bGscxiBsp7B6t0AXfBk', quantity: 1}],
          mode: 'subscription',
          /*
           * Do not rely on the redirect to the successUrl for fulfilling
           * purchases, customers may not always reach the success_url after
           * a successful payment.
           * Instead use one of the strategies described in
           * https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/fulfill-orders
           */
          successUrl: 'https://mypage.co.uk/page',
          cancelUrl: 'https://mypage.co.uk/page',
          customerEmail: '<%=  Company.Utilities2.CWServiceLocator.GetInstance<Company.WebApplications.Mvc.ICWAuthenticationService>().GetUserDetails(Model.UserData.UserID).EmailAddress %>'
        })
        .then(function (result) {
          if (result.error) {
            /*
             * If `redirectToCheckout` fails due to a browser or network
             * error, display the localized error message to your customer.
             */
            var displayError = document.getElementById('error-message');
            displayError.textContent = result.error.message;
          }
        });
      });
    })();
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of supplying the details client-side, you should [create the Checkout session server-side](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment?platform=web&ui=checkout#redirect-customers) before redirecting. Using this approach, you can either [enable customer-entered promotion codes](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-allow_promotion_codes) using `allow_promotion_codes` or [provide explicit discounts](https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-discounts) to use for the session.

Promotion code features are not supported when you supply details client-side like your example shows.